# Adjust linux time/date to a remote server in a different timezone

Tags: python, linux

I have a Centos7 box that has time set with Time Zone in **EDT**. As part of some operation, I need to sync this system's VM with a remote server that is in a different timezone. (**mostly GMT**)

How do I sync my Centos box time to match with that of the remote server's keeping my local time zone intact? Want to do it in python

Comment: Configure your remote server as NTP Server. Then sync with the CentOS box with remote server. Thats simple.May know why you need to do with Python ? Since its direct setup


Reference Link to setup NTP Server Linux
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-configure-ntp-server-and-client-on-almalinux
For Windows Referene Link
https://techlibrary.hpe.com/docs/otlink-wo/How-to-Configure-a-Local-NTP-Server.html

OR 
Sync the Your centos box with Public NTP Server with GMT 
https://www.ntppool.org/en/use.html

Comment: I dont have control over the remote setup, so cannot configure anything in that. I get the time and timezone details of that server during runtime, and I need to sync my Centos box to that timing (retaining my local TZ).